# Simplifying IF/ELSE condition

Tags: javascript

I want to ask how can I simplify my code? It seems hard to read and has too much if-else condition here. Any way to simplify the code?

```
if (e.shiftKey && this.idx > 0) {
  this.idx= this.idx - 1;
} else if (!e.shiftKey && this.idx < trapFocus.length - 1) {
  this.idx = this.idx + 1;
} else if (!e.shiftKey && this.idx < trapFocus.length + 1) {
  this.idx= this.idx - 2;
} else if (e.shiftKey && this.idx > - 1) {
  this.idx= this.idx + 2;
}
```

Comment: Your code is perfectly fine, it is more readable than using ternary.

Comment: you can use Switch Statement.

Comment: Generally this question is better fitted to https://codereview.stackexchange.com. But a simple hint: You could group your cases by `e.shiftKey`. ie `if (e.shiftKey) { if (...)  } else { if (...) }`  Other than that, your code is fine ...

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib How would you use a `switch` for a condition like `if (this.idx < trapFocus.length -1)`?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @derpirscher i missed `!e.shiftKey` :D

Comment: are you sure about `!e.shiftKey && this.idx < trapFocus.length + 1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This first thing you could do is to factor out `e.shiftKey` and use `+=` and `-=` operators

```
if(e.shiftKey)
{
    if(this.idx > 0)
    {
        this.idx -= 1;
    }
    else if(this.idx > -1)
    {
        this.idx += 2;
    }
}
else{
    if(this.idx < trapFocus.length - 1)
    {
        this.idx += 1;
    }
    else if(this.idx < trapFocus.length + 1)
    {
        this.idx -= 2;
    }
}
```

If you ever want to go with ternaries:

```
this.idx += e.shiftKey ? (
        this.idx > 0 ? -1 :
        this.idx > -1 ? 2 : 0
    ) : (
        this.idx < trapFocus.length - 1 ? 1 :
        this.idx < trapFocus.length + 1 ? -2 : 0
    );
```

**Note that this is not necessarily more readable, it just takes up less space.**

Answer (score 3):

You can simply separate the condition using separate `if-else`

```
if (e.shiftKey){
  if(this.idx > 0) this.idx = this.idx - 1;
  else if(this.idx > -1) this.idx = this.idx + 2;
} else {
  if(this.idx < trapFocus.length - 1)) this.idx = this.idx + 1;
  else if(this.idx < trapFocus.length + 1) this.idx < trapFocus.length + 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get it a bit more succinct by using the fact that your if clauses logically imply each other partly.

if `e.shiftKey` is `true` you change something if `this.idx` is 0 or more and if `e.shiftKey` is `false` you change something only if `this.idx < trapFocus.length + 1`:

```
let offset = 0;
if (e.shiftKey){
    if (this.idx >= 0) (this.idx ? offset = -1 : offset = 2)  
} else {
    if (this.idx < trapFocus.length + 1) 
       (this.idx < trapFocus.length - 1 ? offset = 1 : offset = -2)
}
this.idx += offset;
```

**It is not necessarily much more readable.**